# Does check_include_files() work if compiler check (-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS=1) is skipped?

Tags: c, cmake

I am having an issue that I am using a compiler to generate binaries that are only meant to run on a simulator. For this reason cmake configuration errors out saying that my c compiler does not work. As a work around, I have used this command to configure my cmake project:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS=1 ../
```

Which skips the compiler check and proceeds to the next checks.

Now cmake is trying to check other header files:

```
include_directories (/my-libc/include)
include(CheckIncludeFiles)
check_include_files(memory.h HAVE_MEMORY_HEADERS)
check_include_files(stdint.h HAVE_STDINT_HEADERS)
...
```

where "`cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS=1 ../`" yields configuration errors like:

```
-- Looking for include file memory.h
-- Looking for include file memory.h - not found
-- Looking for include file stdint.h
-- Looking for include file stdint.h - not found
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h - not found
-- Looking for include file strings.h
-- Looking for include file strings.h - not found
-- Looking for include file string.h
-- Looking for include file string.h - not found
```

I am having trouble isolating the source of this error. Are all these checks tied to my compiler check skip?

Comment: Building software intended to run in an environment incompatible with the build system's is called "cross compiling".  The CMake documentation contains [a section about it](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/CrossCompiling), which you should probably read before proceeding further.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have not seem this article before, but it looks on point with what I want to do. I will update here when I found the solution. Thanks